# Changing many addresses (in .htaccess)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web

I have table of ids

```
id   | Name     
1    | abc  
2    | xyz
3    | qwe
...  | ... 
1000 | zxc
```

my address looks that: `http://example.com/rat.php?id=1` and I want to make `http://example.com/abc/rat.php` how should I do this, do you have any ideas?

P.S Of course i haven't folder abc, I want just change url in web browwser. I would do like `Rewrite rules`, but i dont know if it will be efficient for every record

Comment: Rewrite to a URL GET parameter, and to a script that takes that parameter and looks up the corresponding content in the database …

Comment: I havent folder abc, I can connect with database and redirect page to for example 'http://exaple.com?name=abc&ac=rat.php` but in every query on my web it will be doing twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(abc)/rat\.php$    rat.php?name=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Or (I would do it like this)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(abc)/rat$ rat.php?name=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

All your links may be rewritten like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/rat$   rat.php?name=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

              ^ this holds all name variations
```

So the name may contain any lowercase, uppercase letter, number or mark `-`

If the rat.php isn't the only file, you may modify the above like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$ index.php?name=$1&file=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

In your PHP (let's use the last example where we have two variables

```
// index.php
//
switch(isset($_GET['file']) ? $_GET['file'] : 'default'){
    case 'rat':
      // load the rat.php for instance
      $something = $_GET['name'];
      break;
    case 'tar':
      // load the tar.php
      // ...
      break;
    default:
      // load index/defautl file 
      break;
}
```

This is the whole logic after. So, as I said in comments below, you don't make any redirections in PHP as they has already done by Apache, using your `.htaccess` file.

You could use the id of the resource in the .htaccess rather than it's name; like this

```
http://example.com/article/an-article-title/10
```

Using this rule

```
RewriteRule ^(article)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?modul=$1&title=$2&id=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

you know the module you need, article in this case, the name (title) of the resource and it's id.

For a permanently moved redirect use `[R=301]`

Comment: and should i write this in htaccess for every record of table?

Comment: @JanQ As you can see all you need is that one line ;)

Comment: @JanQ Check the update, I added another possibility. Why not redirect to index.php and then you decide what (sub)file you need, what to do with this `name` variable etc. As you see, it's quite simple.

Comment: Am I wrong that htacces works first and php parsing is next? I think it won't be works if I do `$_GET['name']='abc'` and i think i should make redirect to example.com?rat.php?name=abc.

Comment: @JanQ By the way, I recommend to use the id of the resource rather than it's name. It's faster. I'll add that example as well.

Comment: I really dont know how should i use it.. 
I have in htaccess simpler exapmle `RewriteBase /RewriteRule ^test/(abc)/rat$ rat.php?name=$1 [NC,L,QSA]` and if i will be get `example.com/test/abc/rat` it doesnt redirect to `example.com/rat.php?name=abc` and the reverse also doesnt work

Comment: @JanQ This `^test/(abc)/rat$ rat.php?name=$1 [NC,L]` or this `^test/(abc)/rat\.php$ rat.php?name=$1 [NC,L]` should redirect to your rat.php if the rewrite engine works on your server. This is a very simple case.

Comment: @JanQ If you are testing this somewhere out of the root, then you should change the `RewriteBase` to `RewriteBase /subfolder`

Comment: @JanQ This is funny, I thought you were using word redirect in a wrong context but now R=301 shows that you didn't need only a rewrite but a (permanently moved) redirect as well :)  Anyhow, glad you/we solved it :)

Comment: Yes but i need do it in reverse and it isn't so easy :P

Comment: @JanQ In reverse :) Could you elaborate it a little plase, maybe adding an update to the question, since I got more familiar with your issue now LOL

Comment: My bad on before.. of course i cant do R=301 :D I know why [NC,L] didnt work, and now it works and it is exactly what i want, but i want also change rat.php?id=1 to /abc/rat.php

Comment: Maybe this `RewriteRule ^rat\.php\?id=1$  /abc/rat.php [NC,L]` never tried :) It should rediect to a subfolder /abc and than to the file rat.php. Anyhow, I'm gonna test it now.

Comment: OK, thanks for helping, I will be try tomorrow to improve that and if i will be have any problems i will be ask :P

Comment: @JanQ Thanks for the accept man. I'm trying to make work the reverse way and I'll drop you a note tomorrow. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

you maybe better search about mvc programming for example php have codeigniter framework that use mvc model ,but i think algorithm for do this 
1-select table with id=1
2-extract name column from table
3-put this column value to string used for url $sitename."/".$row['name']."/rat.php";

i hope will be helpfull for you